# running mke2fs with limited memory

Tags: linux, ext4, mkfs

I'm working on a computer with very little memory (128MB) - for my application I need to format large drives (4TB)

I'm able to format greater than 2TB disks, up to about 2.5TB, but beyond that I'm given the below

```
mke2fs 1.42-WIP (16-Oct-2011)
/dev/sda1: Memory allocation failed while setting up superblock
```

I realize I'm really out there in terms of reasonable - are there any tricks?  (block sizes, etc)

any idea how I can get very large disks to format?

Comment: Put some more RAM in it.

Answer (score 1):

Add some swap: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile1 bs=1024 count=524288
mkswap /swapfile1
swapon /swapfile1
```

That'll make 512MB of swap and enable it. You'll need to edit your `/etc/fstab` to make it stay after a reboot, though.

Answer (score 1):

An even better approach would be to use the `-D` flag.  From the man pages:

> ```
>  Use direct I/O when writing to the  disk.   This  avoids  mke2fs
>  dirtying  a  lot  of buffer cache memory, which may impact other
>  applications running on a busy server.  This option  will  cause
>  mke2fs  to run much more slowly, however, so there is a tradeoff
>  to using direct I/O.
> ```

Worked for me with an `initramfs` and 512MB.

Comment: Better than what? This is unlikely to solve the problem shown in the question.

Comment: This is better than adding swap space.  Also, it's better than "Put some more RAM in it." :-) (albeit probably slower)

Comment: This solved my issue with the same error message on a Raspberry pi. Thank you!